# SFTP in Camel populates wrong parent folder for a file

Tags: apache-camel

Using Camel SFTP consumer that polls remote folder for files, I have the following endpoint configuration:

```
sftp://user@server:22\
    ?password=xxx\
    &delete=false\
    &move=.done\
    &localWorkDirectory=/tmp\
    &delay=60000
```

(`\` is to wrap the end lines in yaml, it all gets stitched together on one line.)

With this setup when the file gets downloaded from user's home directory, it tries to move the remote file to `.done` directory (as per Camel documentation, ".done" should be enough). However, I get exception:

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - 
    Cannot create directory: /.done (could be because of denied permissions)
```

I have the permissions since I could create the directory and rename the file manually using interactive sftp command in bash.

I have debugged through the Camel's processing and found out that the parent folder of the file (CamelFileParent header) is evaluated to `"/"` which means the final path to rename the file is evaluated to `"//.done/some-file-name.csv"`. Which is, of course, wrong and it fails with the above exception.

The question is why it can't resolve the home directory? When I try running `pwd` in interactive sftp command, it resolves correctly to `"/home/user"`.

After debugging more I found out how camel is resolving the parent folder path, and it's purely based on File class, and it does not query the remote server for the parent folder:

```
        String name = getRelativeFilePath();
        File path;
        if (name != null) {
            path = new File(endpointPath, name);
        } else {
            path = new File(endpointPath);
        }
        parent = path.getParent();
```

Where `endpointPath` is `""` and `name` is `"some-file-name.csv"` and so the getParent() call is resolved to `"/"`.

What can I do to get correct home path (without actually hard-coding the path into the endpoint configuration)? Is this a bug?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And also try to set stepwise=false.

Comment: Camel 2.15.3, because of dependencies it's not the latest.

Comment: Maybe if you can then try test with latest release, to see how it runs there. And there is also a 2.15.6 release you can try.